# Why Different charges attract while they should repel?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, field-theory

When I started studying magnetic fields, my teacher was always telling me that strong fields push the bodies to weaker fields, so i tried to apply the same concept to charges in the following picture:

[image: A+B > A-B]

So the stronger field here is (A+B) and the weaker field here is (A-B) so shouldn't these charges repel rather than attract?

Comment: That's...not at all how you draw the electric field of those two charges.

Comment: well at least give me  a link or something ...

Comment: if you are talking about number of lines then yes i know there is more ...

Comment: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/estatics/u8l4c2.gif

Comment: i draw my image based on this

Comment: @ACuriousMind In the context of this question, there is nothing wrong with how he drew the *fields*.

Comment: @garyp: The concept isn't totally wrong, either... I am just not sure how one can explain a volume integral over an electromagnetic energy density at the level of this drawing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Concerning the phrase "strong fields push the bodies to weaker fields":  I have no idea what this means or what your teacher was trying to say.  Positively charged particles are "pushed" in the direction of the electric field, and negatively charged particles are pushed in the opposite direction.  Stronger and weaker makes no sense here.  Charged particles are pushed quite well in a constant field where there is no "stronger" and "weaker"
2. A body does not feel its own field.  The red body in your diagram feels only the force due to the black body, that is, only the black arrows. The black object feels only the force due to the red object (red arrows).    So the red body, being negatively charged, experiences a force in the direction opposite of the black arrows, that is, toward the black object.  The black object, being positively charged, experiences a force in the same direction as the red arrows, that is, toward the red object.

Comment: thanks now i see my mistake , if there were 3 bodies the one in the middle will experience the force of the other two,but two bodies will only affect each other but not themselves.